# Getting only a random item of each category

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well i have two table, categories and items and i would like to get a random record of each of 10 random category.

## tb_category

```
category_id PK
category_name
```

## tb_items

```
item_id PK
category_id FK
```

My table tb_category has about 40 rows and tb_items has about 5k rows, i'm search performance.

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT c.category_id as cid, c.category_name, i.item_id FROM
tb_category c INNER JOIN 
tb_items i ON c.category_id = i.category_id ORDER BY RAND() ) AS ShuffeledItems 
GROUP BY ShuffeledItems.cid limit 10
```

I don't know if that is better way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to use a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select i.item_id
        from items i
        where i.category_id = c.category_id
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) as item_id
from tb_category c
order by c.id
limit 10;
```

Comment: what do u think about this: select b.category_name,a.item_id from tb_items a inner join tb_category b on b.category_id=a.category_id group by a.category_id order by rand() limit 10, but i tnink ur solution is better cuz this query could be slow isn't?

Comment: @JessicaBelao . . . Your version does not use `group by` correctly.  It uses a (mis)feature available in MySQL, one that differs from the ANSI standard and won't work in most databases.

Comment: @JessicaBelao . . . It is at least syntactically correct.

Comment: I mean about performance with with large data like tb_items with about 20k of rows, ur version would be faster than mine query (SELECT * FROM
( SELECT c.category_id as cid, c.category_name, i.item_id FROM
tb_category c INNER JOIN 
tb_items i ON c.category_id = i.category_id ORDER BY RAND() ) AS ShuffeledItems 
GROUP BY ShuffeledItems.cid limit 10)?

Comment: @JessicaBelao . . . You want an index on `tb_items(category_id, item_id)`.

Comment: yes, item_id is primary key and category_id is foreign key with a index also.

Comment: No, one index with two columns -- although in MySQL the foreign key declaration creates an index that will probably include the primary key.

Comment: u mean that item_id should have primary key index and another index with two column category_id,item_id? this will help in performance?